# Parallax scrolling with outer container that has a header and a footer

Tags: html, css, parallax, css-transforms

I have a [CodePen Parallax example](https://codepen.io/neonguru/pen/JmgPvx) that works fine as is. But remove the **display: none** from line 9 in the CSS to show the header and footer and you get 2 scrollbars.

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <header><h1>Header</h1></header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="section parallax">
     <h1>Heading</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Site Content</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer><h1>Footer</h1></footer>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html { 
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}

/* remove the following to see the problem: */
header, footer {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  perspective: 1px;
}

.section {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: white;
}

.parallax::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
  background-size: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: url('http://www.shainblumphoto.com/wp-
             content/uploads/2016/02/dubai_1.jpg');
}

.content {
  height: 200vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: red;
}
```

Does anyone know what change to make to have one scrollbar that includes scrolling of the header and footer, without moving the header and footer to the wrapper, without JavaScript, and still maintain the parallax effect?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow structure.

```
<div class="outer"> 
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header><h1>Header</h1></header>
        <div class="section parallax">
            <h1>Heading</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h1>Site Content</h1>
        </div>
        <footer><h1>Footer</h1></footer>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Updated answer:

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* remove the following to see
   the problem: */

.outer {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  perspective: 1px;
}

.section {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: white;
}

.parallax::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
  background-size: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/800');
}

.content {
  height: 200vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <header>
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="section parallax">
      <h1>Heading</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Site Content</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <h1>Footer</h1>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read my question again. I specifically said I do not want to move the header and footer to the wrapper. It is not possible in my application.

Comment: That looks better. Similar to this one: https://codepen.io/neonguru/pen/zmgMpV
You should change your answer.

Comment: I have resolved your problem. And there is give you a solution not give batter look your website. Thanks